# django-filter not showing filtered items

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I used django-filter in a similar way before and it worked fine, but now when I try to filter my posts it just returns all the items instead of filtering them, can anyone figure what I'm doing wrong?

my filters.py

```
class filtering(django_filters.FilterSet):
class Meta:
    model = Cars
    fields = ['color','body']
```

and my views:

def peugeot_206(request):

```
### Getting Last Month Records of 206 ###

start_date = (datetime.today() - timedelta(30))
end_date = (datetime.today() + timedelta(1))
last_month_records = Cars.objects.filter(datetime__range=(start_date, end_date),car='206')
post_list = last_month_records.order_by('-datetime').values()


### Calculating Aggregations ###

average_price = last_month_records.aggregate(Avg('price'))
min_price = last_month_records.aggregate(Min('price'))
max_price = last_month_records.aggregate(Max('price'))


filters = filtering(request.GET,queryset=post_list)
post_list = filters.qs.values()

### Pagination ###

paginator = Paginator(post_list,10)
page_number = request.GET.get('page')
posts = paginator.get_page(page_number)


return render(request,'main.html',
{
    'average_price':average_price,
    'min_price': min_price,
    'max_price':max_price,
    'posts':posts,
    'paginator':paginator,
    'filters':filters
    })
```

**UPDATE:** it works when I set multiple filters, but when I set a single filter it still shows all the items

**UPDATE 2:** it works fine when I remove datetime__range=(start_date, end_date) from my object filter, does anyone know why ? seems to be a bug

Comment: Please share whole classes of `views`, not only some variables without context.

Comment: sorry,added the whole view